# Mi app no muestra el trazo de la ruta cuando la ejecuto - Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, google-maps, android-fragment

Recurro a ustedes porque mi programa no muestra la ruta en el fragmento de Google Maps. El código no posee error alguno antes de usar el emulador.
Ya actualicé mi versión de Android Studio e hice un clean.
El código de FragmentMap es:

```
package com.example.veo_2.runner;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Location;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;//add
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;//add
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;
import com.google.maps.android.PolyUtil;

import org.json.JSONArray;//add
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.List;//add
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link FragmentMap.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link FragmentMap#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */

public class FragmentMap extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    GoogleMap map;
    Boolean actualPos=true;
    JSONObject jso;
    Double longOrigen, latOrigen;

    public FragmentMap() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment FragmentMap.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static FragmentMap newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FragmentMap fragment = new FragmentMap();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_map, container, false);


        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        return v;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }



    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        map=googleMap;

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
            } else {
                // No explanation needed; request the permission
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                        1);

                // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
                // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                // result of the request.
            }
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
            } else {
                // No explanation needed; request the permission
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        1);

                // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
                // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                // result of the request.
            }
            return;
        }
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener((Location location) -> {


        if(actualPos){
            latOrigen = location.getLatitude();
            longOrigen = location.getLongitude();
            actualPos=false;//una vez

            LatLng miPos = new LatLng(latOrigen, longOrigen);

            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(miPos).title("Acá estoy"));//marker1

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(latOrigen, longOrigen))
                    .zoom(14)
                    .bearing(30)
                    .build();
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

            String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin="+latOrigen+","+longOrigen+"&destination=37.419099,-122.0612867";
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, response -> {
                try {
                    jso = new JSONObject(response);
                    trazarRuta(jso);
                    Log.i("jsonRuta:",""+response);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                trazarRuta(jso);

            }, error -> {

            });

            queue.add(stringRequest);

        }
    });

    }

    private void trazarRuta(JSONObject jso) {


        JSONArray jRoutes;
        JSONArray jLegs;
        JSONArray jSteps;

        try {
            jRoutes = jso.getJSONArray("routes");
            for (int i=0; i<jRoutes.length();i++){

                jLegs = ((JSONObject)(jRoutes.get(i))).getJSONArray("legs");

                for (int j=0; j<jLegs.length();j++){
                    jSteps = ((JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");
                    for (int k = 0; k<jSteps.length();k++){
                        String polyline = ""+((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                        Log.i("end",""+polyline);
                        List<LatLng> list = PolyUtil.decode(polyline);
                        map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().addAll(list).color(Color.CYAN).width(5));
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.
                } else {
                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request.
        }
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Este es el código del MainActivity:

```
package com.example.veo_2.runner;

//import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.net.Uri;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentMap.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Fragment fragment = new FragmentMap();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor, fragment).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }
}
```

En el Event Log, no tengo errores. En el logcat me figuran éstos, pero todos los threads de conversación dicen que son cosas del emulador que no es necesario resolver y que a la hora de usar el celular, desaparecen:

> 08-02 06:59:16.145 5322-5322/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
>   08-02 06:59:16.145 5322-5322/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
>
> 08-02 06:59:26.094 5422-5429/? E/art: Failed writing handshake bytes (-1 of 14): Broken pipe
>
> 08-02 06:59:26.565 1302-1401/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [com.google.android.apps.maps/com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity] cancelBuffer: slot 0 is not owned by the producer (state = ACQUIRED)
>   08-02 06:59:27.953 1302-1904/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property

Aclaro que le asigné un segundo punto cerca de GooglePlex porque el emulador lo toma como posición actual. A todos les sucede lo mismo?

Si tienen sugerencias, los leo. Desde ya, gracias!

Comment: El problema no es el mapa, me lo muestra. Lo que no me muestra es la ruta.

Comment: Ok lo primero que tienes que revisar es si los datos para trazar la ruta son recibidos en el método:  private void trazarRuta(JSONObject jso) {